# CheckBox и js в ASP NET Core С#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

Нужен код, который должен по выбранным чек боксам запись в таблице обновлять.
То есть в таблице, есть строка, (Самосвал), у неё есть чек бокс,
так же, есть ещё одна, такая же строка (Самосвал) и у неё есть чек бокс.
И есть модальное окно (которое появляется, после нажатия на кнопку, выбрать склад) в котором выбирается складо.

Нужно, что бы после нажатия на кнопку (Ок), поля в таблице менялись.
То есть поле IsActive менялось на true, а поле storageId на Id выбранного склада.

По умолчанию поле IsActive = false

вот класс где, должны обновляться свойства

```
public class Stock : Entity
{
    public bool IsCheck { get; set; }
    public string storageId { get; set; }
    public Storage Storage { get; set; }
}
```

вот, код который переберет checkbox:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxChoose" id="checkBoxChoose"/>
                </td>



<div class="modal-footer">
    <div>
        <button id="CreateMethod" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="getCheckedCheckBoxes()">Ok</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Модалка:

```
 <form >
     <div class="form-group" id="stockSelect">
         <label class="control-label">Склады</label>
         <select class="form-control" id="storageId" style="width: 270px !important;" asp-items="ViewBag.storageId"></select>
     </div>
 </form>
```

скрипт:

```
<script>
    function getCheckedCheckBoxes() {
        var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('checkBoxChoose');
        var checkboxesChecked = []; 
        for (var index = 0; index < checkboxes.length; index++) {
            if (checkboxes[index].checked) {
                checkboxesChecked.push(checkboxes[index].value);
                console.log(checkboxes[index].value);
            }
        }
        return checkboxesChecked;
    }
</script>
```

вместо строчки `console.log(checkboxes[index].value);` 
нужно сделать ajax запрос (POST)  в метод если я правильно мыслю!

Пробовал вот так:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/Stocks/Check',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            stock: {
                IsActive: $('#checkBoxChoose').val()
                storageId: $('#StorageId').val()
            }
        }),
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
});
```

Вот метод который должен принимать данные с запроса

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Check(Stock stock, string id, bool isActiveTrue, string storageId) 
{
    var isActiveTrue = _context.Stock
            .Where(i => i.Id == id)
            .FirstOrDefault(i => i.IsActive);

        if (!isActive)
        {
            if (isActiveTrue != null)
            {
                isActiveTrue.IsActive = false;
                isActiveTrue.OfficeId = officeId;
                _context.Update(isActiveTrue);
            }

            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
    return Json(new { success = true });
}
```

Вроде все элементы есть а, как их соединить не пойму. То есть на данный момент ajax запрос и метод Check не как не связанны со скриптом. Это я как раз и не пойму как их связать. Буде благодарен за любую помощь,  не один час сижу, не могу понять как сделать.

добавил функцию:

```
function AjaxPost() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Stock/Check',
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    stock: {
                        IsActive: $('#checkBoxChoose').val(),
                        storageId: $('#storageId').val()
                    }
                }),
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log("work");
                }
            });
        }
```

вызов делаю так `AjaxPost();`

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88170/discussion-on-question-by-eugenetm-checkbox--js--asp-net-core-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблему решил через `onchange='OnChancheSorageId(this)'` передав туда `this` и в функцию передал `(е)`, так получил нужные id и передал его через ajax в метод, после чего в методе записал в базу `storageId` и изменил `IsActive` на `true`.